# .htaccess conflict with css

Tags: css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I have 1 page

```
https://domainsanalytics.com/country.php
```

I am passing values like

```
https://domainsanalytics.com/country.php?id=219
```

I want to make SEO friendly URLs like

```
https://domainsanalytics.com/country/219
```

That I try to accomplish by this

```
RewriteRule ^(country)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

But that gives me a bug on my pages, example: `https://domainsanalytics.com/country/219`

If i add before the above code,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

That work for

```
https://domainsanalytics.com/country
```

but 404 on

```
https://domainsanalytics.com/country/219
```

I need help to make sure both work well

```
    https://domainsanalytics.com/country/219
    and
    https://domainsanalytics.com/country
```

PS : When you open website htaccess has only

```
RewriteRule ^(country)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(tld)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(registrar)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

and screenshot

[image: http://domainsanalytics.com/]

**EDIT**

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(country)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(tld)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(registrar)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

That work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(tld|registrar|country)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

JS/CS rewrite/redirect:
You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: it show me same error... I add only your code.. not anything else. it still show same errors...

Comment: @Amit, what is the url you are hitting, a sample url will help here, thank you.

Comment: https://domainsanalytics.com/country/219 and https://domainsanalytics.com/country

Comment: @Amit, Please try my edited rules file once and clear your browser cache then try urls once. let me know how it goes then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I think the OP's problem has been solved. The thing is that some users do not want to come back to leave feedback once their query is solved. Anyways Already ++ Ravinder for your in-depth answer. It's really helpful for future readers having the similar problem.

Comment: @AmitVerma, Thank you Amit sir :) Let's hope OP's problem is solved :) yeah OP's should come back for their feedback, I agree on that point.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13. what is [QSA,NC,L] for?

Comment: @AmitVerma patience is virtue

Comment: @Amit, `QSA` is for query string adding, `NC` is for ignorecase(to match any string), `L` that this is last rule for matched condition cheers and happy learning :)

Comment: @Amit, hey mate, he is simply kidding, you both are Cool guys(with same name), cheers :)